# Merge two arrays , So that both 1st index is in new array and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have two arrays like this

1st array is

```
array1[
0:"7@a.com"
1:"6@live.com"
2:"5@live.com"
3:"55@a.com"
4:"4@live.com"
5:"3@live.com"
6:"62@a.com"
7:"61@a.com"
8:"61@a.com"
9:"59@a.com"
10:"58@a.com"
```

And array two in same way like this

```
0"5223b14d-1682-4777-8ada-c5b0c972756f"
1:"290c79e8-62da-46f1-bff5-157031a079fa"
2:"eb4ff5f9-82c7-4095-8116-1c34f1755d06"
3:"987c51f4-23f1-4783-8061-a47dfff16fe3"
4:"afcf5ef1-a87d-465f-bb1b-f8db81ecc178"
5:"2d299d60-9481-4c3f-9b9b-e6659ee74d07"
6:"1f40b5ef-990f-4edd-925c-b511dd64899f"
7:"88de17fd-286f-4960-9e4f-a2b01425da82"
8:"1bb181cb-ab7c-47af-95a6-99357459e6a3"
9:"9554f7c2-a20d-4ff7-add6-8840b2d06a89"
10:"15e51955-9eb9-4c4b-990f-97e29820e04d"
```

now I want to make 10 new arrays with combinations of indexs of both like

```
newarray=[array1[0],array2[0]];
```

I got the algo but dont know how can I loop through on both. as I tried but got just words of both. And I tried 3,4 soloution on stak overflow but didnt work for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
array1 = [ "7@a.com", "6@live.com", "5@live.com", "55@a.com", "4@live.com", "3@live.com", "62@a.com", "61@a.com", "61@a.com", "59@a.com", "58@a.com"]; array2 = [
"5223b14d-1682-4777-8ada-c5b0c972756f", "290c79e8-62da-46f1-bff5-157031a079fa", "eb4ff5f9-82c7-4095-8116-1c34f1755d06", "987c51f4-23f1-4783-8061-a47dfff16fe3", "afcf5ef1-a87d-465f-bb1b-f8db81ecc178", "2d299d60-9481-4c3f-9b9b-e6659ee74d07", "1f40b5ef-990f-4edd-925c-b511dd64899f", "88de17fd-286f-4960-9e4f-a2b01425da82", "1bb181cb-ab7c-47af-95a6-99357459e6a3", "9554f7c2-a20d-4ff7-add6-8840b2d06a89", "15e51955-9eb9-4c4b-990f-97e29820e04d"];

var newArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
    newArray.push([ array1[i], array2[i]]);
console.log( newArray );
```

Comment: thank you @jarek Kulikowski I done it :) thank you so so much . accepting after 3 minutes ;)

Comment: array + loop + push for every element/index -> [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @ephemeral my pleasure :).

Comment: @Andreas what do you mean ?

Comment: @ephemeral That the construct (create an array, loop over another array and push a modified version of each element in the newly created array) can be replaced by `.map()` (like in the answers of chsdk and Ori)

Answer (score 4):

If the arrays length is equal, you can just use `map()` method to loop over one of them and return a custom array with both elements:

```
var results = arr1.map(function(el, index){
    return [el, arr2[index]];
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr1 = ["7@a.com","6@live.com","5@live.com","55@a.com","4@live.com","3@live.com","62@a.com","61@a.com","61@a.com","59@a.com","58@a.com"];

    var arr2 = ["5223b14d-1682-4777-8ada-c5b0c972756f","290c79e8-62da-46f1-bff5-157031a079fa","eb4ff5f9-82c7-4095-8116-1c34f1755d06","987c51f4-23f1-4783-8061-a47dfff16fe3","afcf5ef1-a87d-465f-bb1b-f8db81ecc178","2d299d60-9481-4c3f-9b9b-e6659ee74d07","1f40b5ef-990f-4edd-925c-b511dd64899f","88de17fd-286f-4960-9e4f-a2b01425da82","1bb181cb-ab7c-47af-95a6-99357459e6a3","9554f7c2-a20d-4ff7-add6-8840b2d06a89","15e51955-9eb9-4c4b-990f-97e29820e04d"];
    
var results = arr1.map(function(el, index){
    return [el, arr2[index]];
});
    
console.log(results)
```

Comment: If the arrays are different lengths here is a simple approach that solves this https://github.com/vikramcse/zip-array/blob/master/index.js

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes or we can just add a condition to check if the `index` isn't higher than the second array `length`.

Answer (score 3):

You can map them into pairs of values:

```js
var array1 = ["7@a.com","6@live.com","5@live.com","55@a.com","4@live.com","3@live.com","62@a.com","61@a.com","61@a.com","59@a.com","58@a.com"];

var array2 = ["5223b14d-1682-4777-8ada-c5b0c972756f","290c79e8-62da-46f1-bff5-157031a079fa","eb4ff5f9-82c7-4095-8116-1c34f1755d06","987c51f4-23f1-4783-8061-a47dfff16fe3","afcf5ef1-a87d-465f-bb1b-f8db81ecc178","2d299d60-9481-4c3f-9b9b-e6659ee74d07","1f40b5ef-990f-4edd-925c-b511dd64899f","88de17fd-286f-4960-9e4f-a2b01425da82","1bb181cb-ab7c-47af-95a6-99357459e6a3","9554f7c2-a20d-4ff7-add6-8840b2d06a89","15e51955-9eb9-4c4b-990f-97e29820e04d"];

var result = array1.map(function(v1, i) {
  return [v1, array2[i]];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is v1 here ?

Comment: The value from array1.

Comment: I want to make new array , but Its not making new array of combination of two

Comment: Droi I need 10 arrays with 2 values each

Comment: I done it already with @Jarek solution. Your code as well working thank you . So giving you thumbup/